# Golden ratio in hinduism

Tags: mathematics, numerology

Christianity talks of the golden ratio. I have read about it from the Da Vinci Code. Is there anything similar to the golden ratio in Hinduism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2nd century BCE Sanskrit grammarian Pingala's Chandahśāstra 8.32-33 which while classifying poetic meters of long and short syllables, presents the Mount Meru (Meru-Prastāra, ‘steps of Mount Meru’, but Meru-Khanda, ‘portion of Mount Meru’ by Bhāskara II in his Līlāvatī written in 1150), which is also known as the Pascal’s triangle.

The shallow diagonals of the Mount Meru sum to the Fibonacci series, whose 
limiting ratio is the golden mean.<sup>1</sup>

[image]

**Reference:**

1. [The Golden Mean and the Physics of Aesthetics](http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0411195.pdf), Subhash Kak, Louisiana State University, Baton Rouge

Comment: Did Pingala actually discuss the sums of the shallow diagonals.  And assuming that he did, did he specifically discuss the ratio of the sums of the shallow diagonals, let alone what they approach?

Comment: In my references I could only find that he formulated the triangle. Golden ratio can be derived from it. Just as one would derive it from Pascal's triangle. I don't understand the purpose of your question. You mean that if he did not explicitly mention it, then the claim that it contains the golden ratio is false? 
Maybe you could provide a better answer.

Comment: Yes, my point is that knowing about Pascal's triangle is not the same as knowing about the Fibbonaci series, and knowing about the Fibbonaci series is not the same as knowing about the golden ratio.  I'm pretty sure you can even obtain the Bernoulli numbers from Pascal's triangle, but it would be absurd to say that the ancient Indians knew about the Bernoulli numbers just because they knew about Pascal's triangle.

Comment: The same applies to Christianity too as mentioned in OP's question. Nowhere in the Bible have they derived the golden ratio. Since OP used Christianity as an example, using the same kind of example we could say golden ratio exists in Hinduism. If the OP's question was formulated differently, the answer would be different.

Comment: Well, I think the OP is simply wrong when they say "Christianity talks of the golden ratio."

Comment: @Bharat, Keshav Srinivasan I mentioned of the golden ratio indeed. However I also mentioned that I have received an idea about its existence from the Da Vinci Code. I know that is a work of fiction by Dan Brown; however it does have factual references. So, I wanted to know about that. In case the book has misguided me, could you please let me know about correct references?

Comment: Doesn't Fibonacci series generate only ab approximate Golden Ratio? Although this is Maths oriented so I don't know whether this goes on this site.

Comment: @Surya If you take the n +1st Fibbonacci number and you divide it by the nth Fibbonaci number, and you take the limit as n goes to infinity, that equals the golden ratio.  That's what Bharat meant by the "limiting ratio".

Answer (score 4):

Golden ratios do exist in Hindu temples  and it is called deva pramana. Sculptures of Hindu deities mostly incorporate deva pramana.This aspect is discussed in the book " science and golden ratios in mandala architecture" by Rekha Rao, DK print world.

Comment: Dear Rekha Rao, I'm very interested in the relationship between golden ration and Hindu temples. I believe everything comes from Veda. So, even golden ratio.  But I do not know "deva pramana" architecture. Could you tell me exactly which temples are constracted by golden ratio?